# SU Review, how to stop "watching" a tag

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, review

On the [review](https://superuser.com/review) page, I selected a tag to see the questions needed review for that specific subject. But now, I can't find a way to go back and see all the tags combined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like missing functionality.

However, you can remove the `&tag=tagname` part of the URL if you want to.

Comment: I think the site stores a cookie or something because when I select a tag and refresh, the url changes to http://superuser.com/review but the tag is still selected.

Comment: @MaxMackie: If you click on the tab, you get that part back. I suppose it's stored server side so it survives logging out and also works across other computers...

Comment: Got it, thanks. Weird.

Comment: Weird. maybe ping [@waffles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles) about it, he's in charge of the whole thing. I don't think he comes by this place very often @MaxMackie

Answer (score 3):

I just "unstickyied" tags, so to revert to full listing you would click on the "tools" or "review" link depending on your rep.

I think the idea of remembering the tag filter was ill conceived.